# GWT Application does not work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I have a web app developed with GWT. In any browser except IE everything works fine. In IE 7, 8 or 9 it breaks.

The link is https://dev.sertal.net/SertalVision/?locale=de#LoginPlace:test:sertal.ch

In any Browser, the username is filled with test and the tenant with sertal.ch

The solution I found is to tell people to install ChromeFrame, but one reason I chose GWT was for its browser portability.

The error message in IE is:

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 27 Apr 2011 12:47:25 UTC


Message: 'ch_sertal_vision_client_model_ClientUser_firstName' is null or not an object
Line: 5490
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://micharoon.adb.intra.admin.ch:8080/SertalVision/sertalvision/96253B890BCF313B6DB7F1C5768930F2.cache.html
```

which is located in a function:

```
function ch_sertal_vision_client_view_TopPanel_$setUser__Lch_sertal_vision_client_view_TopPanel_2Lch_sertal_vision_client_model_ClientUser_2V(this$static, user){
  com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_DirectionalTextHelper_$setTextOrHtml__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_DirectionalTextHelper_2Ljava_lang_String_2ZV(this$static.ch_sertal_vision_client_view_TopPanel_userSettings.com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_LabelBase_directionalTextHelper, user.ch_sertal_vision_client_model_ClientUser_firstName + $intern_43 + user.ch_sertal_vision_client_model_ClientUser_lastName + $intern_225 + user.ch_sertal_vision_client_model_ClientUser_userName + $intern_226, false);
  com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_DirectionalTextHelper_$setTextOrHtml__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_DirectionalTextHelper_2Ljava_lang_String_2ZV(this$static.ch_sertal_vision_client_view_TopPanel_tenantName.com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_LabelBase_directionalTextHelper, ch_sertal_vision_client_model_NamedElement_$getName__Lch_sertal_vision_client_model_NamedElement_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2(user.ch_sertal_vision_client_model_ClientUser_tenant, $intern_42), false);
}
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Micha

Comment: What specifically happens? When you use the F12 Script debugger, are there any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

IE can not handle NullPointerExceptions as well as others. I corrected the NullPointer and now it works.

Setting the GWT output style to DETAILED allowed me to identify what was wrong.

For future notice, the maven plugin config:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt-maven-plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
       <style>DETAILED</style>
       <logLevel>TRACE</logLevel>
       <runTarget>/SertalVision.html</runTarget>
       <inplace>false</inplace>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <goals>
             <!-- <goal>mergewebxml</goal> -->
             <goal>compile</goal>
             <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```